# Why is a topic locked as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Why is this topic locked as off-topic?

[grep: show lines surrounding each match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-show-lines-surrounding-each-match)

This seems totally arbitrary. Please explain why and by whom are topics like this locked.

Comment: That question is about an OS (Unix) command line command's syntax, and is not considered a direct programming topic. But it is an old and highly voted question with high visibility, asked and answered before question topic requirements were changed, and so rather than deleting it, as would be the case if it were a more recent question with lower visibility, it has been locked.

Comment: The [help] has an entire article on [locked posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts); explain what didn't you understand about that, and we can try to elaborate.

Comment: The banner at the top seems pretty clear: "This question and its answers are locked **because the question is off-topic but has historical significance.**" As Thom A said, can you elaborate on what exactly you're confused about?

Comment: "This seems totally arbitrary" - you forgot to explain *why* it would be arbitrary though. Because you believe the site has no rules? Because it is an old highly upvoted post and therefore "it must be okay" ? What is your reasoning here?

Comment: I do "love" a good ol' "ask and abandon".

Comment: "This seems totally arbitrary." - Did you try reading [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? Did it at least occur to you that there might be such a page? Did you try to look for one?

Comment: Well, it wasn't actually _closed_ with a specific off-topic reason before the lock was applied.  I've now corrected this.

Comment: After 31 down votes, a moderator comes in, admits it to be a mistake and corrects it. Sigh.

Comment: It's *still* locked, @MattiJokipii , it's just closed now too. It being locked wasn't a mistake.